# How do I change values in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

So I have this code for homework that I must debug with gdb. I have found the problem but don't know how to use gdb to change it

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 12
for (i = ARRAYSIZE - 2; i > 0; i--) {
    for (j = i; j < ARRAYSIZE - 1; j++) {
```

I know that the solution to the problem is this:

```
for (i = ARRAYSIZE; i > 0; i--) {
    for (j = i-1; j < ARRAYSIZE - 1; j++) {
```

But don't know how to change the parameters in the for loop. I've tried it this way but it doesn't work:

```
81        for (i = ARRAYSIZE - 2; i > 0; i--) {
(gdb) set var i=12
(gdb) p i
$1 = 12
(gdb) n
82          for (j = i; j < ARRAYSIZE - 1; j++) {
(gdb) set var j=i-1
(gdb) p j
$2 = 9
(gdb) p i
$3 = 10
```

I've also tried using `print i=12` and `print j=i-1` to change the values but the result is the same.

Comment: Why are you trying to change source code in `gdb` instead of in the original file?

Comment: @merlin2011 It's for homework to learn how to debug code with gdb. They want us to use gdb exclusively and not to touch the actual code.

Comment: `gdb` is used for *finding* bugs, not *fixing* bugs...

Comment: @merlin2011 I know but there's nothing _I_ can do about it...

Comment: @merlin2011 This is not about changing the source code. This is about modifying variables in a running program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the `i = ARRAYSIZE - 2`  part of the for loop havn't executed yet.

So you're setting `i` to `12` and the next thing that's executed is `i = ARRAYSIZE - 2` that sets `i` to 10.

I don't know any easy way to step through the different exprssions of a for loop, but you can change `i`  with e.g. `set var i = 10` once you reach the next source code line.