# GDB to change the value for a for loop

Tags: c, gdb

```
void bubble_sort ()
{
 #define ARRAYSIZE 12
 int array[ARRAYSIZE] = { 5, 7, 99, 12, 42, 31, 1, 45, 9, 21, 22, 23 };
 int i, j, temp;

 for (i = ARRAYSIZE - 2; i > 0; i--) {
   for (j = i; j < ARRAYSIZE - 1; j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
          } else {
             break;
                  }
   }
   }

      private_sort_check (array);
     }
```

I need to correct this code using gdb only. I am not allowed to make any physical change to the .c file. I know I have to change the following statement 
       for (i = ARRAYSIZE - 2; i > 0; i--) 
    to 
     for (i = ARRAYSIZE - 2; i >= 0; i--) to make it work.

My problem is how to change the value? I know how to change a value for a variable and that is by using print but I have no idea about this. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I have never used gdb before. I have just started 2 days back

Comment: Don't know what you want to do. Looks like you want to change the compare operator at run-time? It is impossible because it is stored at code section and read-only.

Comment: I know that is why I am asking is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: @Holsety You do know it's possible to change memory protection flags, right? (How do you think your program gets loaded in the first place?)

Comment: Run until `i` is 0. Break at the first `for` line. Change `i` to 1. Step to get past the first `for`. Change `i` back to 0. Run. I haven't actually tried it so there might be some gotchas depending on how the code was compiled. But hopefully opens up a line of thought.

Comment: @immibis I know few about it. Thanks to teach me.

Comment: @kaylum I followed your advice and I was able to do it. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24374705/3393574